# Ошибка истечения таймаута запроса через axios

Tags: php, apache, клиент-сервер, axios

При создании React компонента происходит запрос к серверу через axios для получения данных представления, в моем случае это просто запрос к php-скрипту из соседней папки. Проблема в том, что по неясной причине запрос успешен примерно в 80% случаев - данные приходят и все ок, но иногда, после некоторого ожидания, выбрасывается ошибка об истечении timeout axios, будь он хоть 5/10/15/etc секунд, ощущение, что до самого php-скрипта дело вообще не доходит, на стороне php просто отдаются данные при попадании в route, всегда одинаково при нижеописанном запросе, никаких сложных расчетов и sleep нет.

> upd. Проблема на стороне сервера, слишком долгий ответ при имитации
> GET-запроса через postman, периодически возвращается пустое тело, без
> ошибок и прочего. Может это что-то в настройках PHP или Apache?

Настройки Axios

```
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "/api/",
    timeout: 1000 * 5,
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Запрос

```
api.get(uri)
    .then(responce => dispatch({ type: "received", payload: responce.data }))
    .catch(error => dispatch({ type: "error", payload: error }))
```

При выводе ошибки в консоль просто пишется:

```
error from server in action received: timeout of 5000ms exceeded
```

> Заголовки.
>
> **Успешный:**

```
General

Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/category/phones
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/category/phones
X-KL-Ajax-Request: Ajax_Request
```

> **Тот, что возвращается при ошибке таймаута**

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/category/phones
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:3000/category/phones
X-KL-Ajax-Request: Ajax_Request
```

PHP-скрипт

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
    $uri = trim(filter_var($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    print json_encode(Request::getCategoryData($uri, 5));
}


    public static function getCategoryData($uri, $limit = null)
    {
        // тут я сократил, просто извлечение из uri подстроки для названия 
        // таблицы категории, типа phones/gadgets/etc
        $category_products_table = $uri; 
        
        $products_query = $limit
            ? "SELECT * FROM {$category_products_table} LIMIT {$limit}"
            : "SELECT * FROM {$category_products_table}";

        $pdo = Connect::exec()->prepare($products_query);
        $pdo->execute();
        return $pdo->fetchAll();
    }
```

Comment: выглядит действительно загадочно. А сервер на той же машине, или запрос куда то перенаправляется?

Comment: Нет, все на одном компьютере, Апач + PHP 7.2

Comment: А если подёргать PHP скрипт postmen'ом - то же самое будет? в смысле, примерно каждый пятый запрос будет повисать?

Comment: Нет, так проблем нет, сам скрипт работает нормально, там по сути ломаться особо нечему, просто отдача массива из пяти элементов при определенном GET-параметре.

Comment: я рассуждаю так: в сети вроде нет проблем. потому что локалхост. Значит, или браузер не посылает запрос, или сервер не отвечет. Надо пробовать понять, кто из них двоих виноват. Можете дополнить вопрос, приведя php - может, кто то из знатоков что то заметит и посоветует.

Comment: ок, добавил скрипт

Comment: Я глянул поверхностно... А не может быть так, что коннект с базой не установился? просто если понажимать  на кнопочку в постмене - это сняло бы вопрос. Больше, к сожалению, не могу ничего посоветовать

Comment: Попробуйте всё таки: https://www.postman.com/

Comment: Попробовал, вы правы, проблема на стороне сервера, через десктопный postman периодически запрос возвращает пустоту, даже ошибки нет, просто пустое окно ответа, при этом время запроса продолжает крутиться. Я пробовал в самом начале скрипта просто выводить через print слово start, чтоб знать, что скрипт хоть работать начал, но при пустом ответе он даже это не показывает.

Comment: Смотрите логи сервера, или добавляйте их для лучшего понимания ситуации

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, я добавил в httpd.conf вывод CustomLog, так вот, даже на запрос, который висит на postman без ответа, с пустым телом, пришел статус 200, может какие-то специфические директивы есть под такие ситуации?

Comment: Обычно это означает что у сервера недостаточно рабочих процессов - это лучше проверить, увеличив их.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в антивирусе Касперского, его отключение избавило от всех проблем с запросами. После трех суток поиска ошибок, установки разных версий Апача и PHP, чтения логов до пяти утра, закажу пожалуй себе футболку с такой надписью - "Проблема была в антивирусе Касперского".